# Bootstrap's navbar list item changes its color on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue in Bootstrap's navbar.
When I right click on one of the list items(link) to redirect it to the another page, it keeps it's color is orange (i.e. actually a hover color), when I click outside the navbar,the color changes to default color (i.e. green).
Why it's all happening?

I think it should keep it default green color even after right click.
Below is the picture of navbar, after I right click on it to move to Shopping page.

[image]

CSS Code

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {

  color: #6ecd6e;
  font-size:15.7px;
  font-weight:400;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that's because of the `:active` state of the link element. Add it to your CSS and define the color for it. Also a heads up: `font-size: 15.7px` won't work.

Comment: @Roy
following is the already written css in my code.
Are you talking about this?
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #6ecd6e;
  font-size: 15.7px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffb600;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-default">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this particular situation based on right clicking as described...what is happening is right clicking is causing the link to be focused, which is why the link is staying orange.  In my example I moved the a:focus up to where the green color was declared.